# C# Linq - .ForEach updating all property value of the collection

Tags: c#, linq

When using `.ForEach` to update the `RemarkText` property in an object. It is updating the `RemarkText` property value on the remarksToDelete`and`endTransactionResponse` property.

```
        private List<Remark> GetElementsToDelete(Gds.Response.CreateResponse endTransactionResponse, List<Remark> ticketRemarks, List<Remark> elementsToAdd)
        {
            var remarksToDelete = new List<Remark>();
            foreach (var ticketRemark in ticketRemarks)
            {
                ticketRemark.RemarkText = TrimEnd(ticketRemark.RemarkText);

                var remarks = endTransactionResponse.Remarks.Where(
                    x => x.RemarkType == ticketRemark.RemarkType
                    && (x.RemarkType == RemarkTypes.END || this.remarkText.Any(x.RemarkText.ToUpper().Contains))
                    && x.GdsReference != null
                    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.GdsReference.GdsReferenceId));

                if (remarks.Any())
                {
                    remarks.Where(x => !x.RemarkText.Contains(PassengerTypes.INF.ToString()))
                        .ToList()
                        .ForEach(x => x.RemarkText = ticketRemark.RemarkText);
                    remarksToDelete.AddRange(remarks);
                }
                else
                {
                    elementsToAdd.Add(ticketRemark);
                }
            }

            return remarksToDelete;
        }
```

I tried to use `ToList()` with `endTransactionResponse.Remarks.Where(...).ToList()`, also tried to add new list `new List(newRemarks)`, I also tried to use `.Select(x => { x.RemarkText = ticketRemark.RemarkText; return x });` but none work for me.

Why this is happening? How can we fix the problem?

The response will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `ForEach` isn't a LINQ operation. It's a `List` operation. It's executed on a list created by `ToList()` that's never stored anywhere.

Comment: `remarks` itself is a query (actually an enumerable), not data. Every time it's accessed the enumerable will be evaluated and enumerated again.

Comment: But when trying to use .Select to update the property value. It is also not working as expected.

Comment: `Remarks` is a reference type, quite likely. You are not creating new `Remarks` instances when adding them to remarksToDelete. You just add _references_ of those `Remarks` instances to remarksToDelete. So, the remarksToDelete list will contain references to the _same_ objects as found in endTransactionResponse.Remarks.

Comment: OK, seriously, don't do that. GDS responses are huge, complex, and this code is generating a *ton* of temporary objects. The *last* thing you want is try go debug some ''clever" code in some 50-level deep, 200-record response from Amadeus Master Pricer or Sabre's Search

Comment: @mubeen `also not working as expected` all this code is full of problems. Instead of working with lists, it iterates over the original GDS responses, modifying *them*. The `remarksToDelete` *are* the actual response elements, not a copy

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes there are a lot of problem. I am not much experienced with C# and I am struggling with it.

Comment: Instead of modifying existing objects in `ForEach` create *new* ones with `Select` and a `new` clause. Copy any data you want from the response objects. Materialize the `remarks` by calling `ToList()` at the end of the query. This way you can check the list's length to see if there are any results instead of iterating over the entire response again

Comment: Alright, let me try. Thank you so much for the response!

Comment: Finally, just looking at `ToUpper()` and `ToString()` freaks me out. GDS responses are huge so creating new temporary strings like this results in *big* allocation and garbage collection costs, that in turn translate to more servers for the same traffic *and* increased delays in providing results. You can use case-invariant versions of `String.Equals` instead of `ToUpper()`.

Comment: Much appreciate. I have learned new stuff from you. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify everything using a normal foreach acting over the IEnumerable remarks and extracting only the remarks that you need to delete.

```
if(remarks.Any())
{
    foreach(Remark r in remarks.Where(x => !x.RemarkText.Contains(PassengerTypes.INF.ToString()))
    {
         r.RemarkText = ticketRemark.RemarkText;
         remarksToDelete.Add(r);
    }
}
```

In your code you create a new List with ToList() and then proceed to change the RemarkText for every object materialized by the ToList(). But this list is never assigned to anything. Not certainly to the *remarks* IEnumerable, so your changes are lost.